# Static Month Every Year Parameter SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to have a parameter that selects the same month (which is September) every year. So this Parameter dynamically changes every year but still selects September.

Comment: Something similar to this: =dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today()),month(Today()),1)) 

but only selecting September as the month every year that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about changing the month the the static date. Took me a few tweaks but I was able to figure it out. It was actually pretty easy stuff. Feel free to post other methods. Method I used was:

=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today()),9,1))

Comment: If this answer solves your problem please mark your answer as the solution to your own question.